# Not able to PASTE data-range from clipboard to selected cell of other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How to handle paste data-range from clipboard when at end of certain macro execution.

**Work flow**

> **COPY** form workbook1 to clip board >> **workbook2_activate** macro
>   running >> workbook2_subroutine to **PASTE** range from clipboard to
>   worksheet of workbook2

**Code**

```
Sub PasteFromClipboard()

    Set clipboard = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    ' Or
    'Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    'Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

    clipboard.GetFromClipboard

    ' error induced on all following codes
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

**Workbook-1 : Snapshot**

[image: Snapshot]

**Workbook-2 : Macro error**

[image]

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: please refer workflow of code mentioned in problem statement